# content relationship in views

Tags: 8, views

I have a view and I need to relate contents, the problem is that you do not show me the data. 
Two contents: 1. productions, 2. functions (theater).
the functions are related to the productions, but inversely not.

I need to create a cover of productions, which contain the dates of the functions with the link of your purchase.

[image]
example:
[image]

Manage  Field: functions

[image]

products, they have no related field
Thank you very much!

Add a similar problem, on the same types of content.
Is list of productions:

[image]
I can not add a list with this design. Add views

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce `functions` fields into your `productions` views by adding a Relationship through the Entity reference field.

1. Add a new Relationship **Content referenced from field_production_content**
2. Add a new Field `field_date_functions` and set it to use the Relationship `field_production_content`
3. Add a new Field `field_tiket_link_functions` and set it to use the Relationship `field_production_content`

If I understood your structure correctly you'll see functions fields on their related functions nodes in Views results.

Comment: add a field with the content of functions in my production content. it is right?

Comment: And if I have a list of productions that have to show the dates their corresponding functions, I use the same steps.

Comment: Yes. Once you create the Relationship, you will see the functions fields become available to add under Fields. If you don't add the Relationship you can only add production fields because of your content type Filter (Producciones).

Comment: Your block has Content: ID contextual filter, it probably filters only the Production node you're currently visiting. 

But the same procedure applies on a Page listing all Producciones. Add a Relationship, then Fields from the functions using that Relationship. Maybe change your format to Table to display the info in a nicer way.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that only with a relation in a content (example in functions) it was possible to obtain the contents of the other content (production example). To finish, you must add relations (type reference) in both contents to show your data in a filtering criterion. Example
`Content: Content type (= Functions)` all production data, and in reverse
`Content: Content type (= Productions) ` you have to have a relationship to obtain the data of the functions.

Comment: It all depends on what Views you're building it. If you have Functions Views, then you don't need a Relationship to show function fields. But if you also want to show Production fields (not just the title because that is available in Entity reference), then you do need the Relationship. I don't expect you'd need 2 Relationships (both ways) unless you need it in Block for the Contextual filter. But you don't have that special case, Content: ID is enough for Producciones to display their related functions.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have solved the problem of the cover thanks to you. But now I have problems with the list of all productions.

Comment: Is it similar to this question, Relationships? If not you can start a new question and include all the relevant information like you did here.

Comment: OK, now add new topics about relationships.

Comment: The only way I can think of showing multiple function dates in each Production row is by using [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view). Create one View with only Dates, and ID contextual filter, then add that View to your original Production View, as a field within each Production.

Comment: Do you have any _Views Field View_ tutorial?

Comment: You can Google it, there are video ones if you prefer. Here's one: [Drupal Views Inside Other Views](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/views-field-view/).